# regex contraint to match md5 hash in zend routing

Tags: regex, zend-framework2

Below is the routing defined in my module.

```
        'download' => array(
            'type'      => 'Segment',
            'options'   => array(
                'route' => '/download[/:transferId][/:receiverId]',
                'constraints' =>array(
                    'transferId' => '/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/i',
                    'receiverId' => '/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/i'
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller'    => 'FileServer\Controller\Web',
                    'action'        => 'download',
                )
            )
        ),
```

And these urls were expected to match `http://localhost/download/229def85ea0ccfcd6809053cb8fc4911` and this `http://localhost/download/229def85ea0ccfcd6809053cb8fc4911/229def85ea0ccfcd6809053cb8fc4911` but none are matched

Apart from this regex in the constraint `/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/i` I tried these aswell but its not working

```
^[a-fA-F0-9]{32}$
[a-fA-F0-9]{32}
[a-f0-9]{32}
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want:

```
'constraints' => array(
    'transferId' => '[a-f0-9]{32}',
    'receiverId' => '[a-f0-9]{32}'
),
```

(You don't include the other parts of the regex as ZF2 is combining all the constraints into one regex pattern.)

See the docs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-segment for more examples.

Comment: It was my very first expression. However it might have not worked because there was another bug in route url. Now `[a-fA-F0-9]{32}` (which I included in initial post) and even `[a-fA-F\d]{32} (which I tried but not inluded in post) are working.

Answer (score 0):

> Apart from this regex in the constraint `/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/i` I tried
>   these as well but its not working
>
> `^[a-fA-F0-9]{32}$` `[a-fA-F0-9]{32}`

This didn't work because `[a-f0-9]{32}` matches only an alphabet or a number 32 times, whereas in your string, there is a semicolon `:`, and a forward slash `/`.

You can make use of this pattern

```
http:\/\/\S+
```

this strictly ensures that `http://` is present in the match

see [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gD8wO2/4)

if you want a more general pattern, use this

```
[a-z]+:\/\/\S+
```

see [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gD8wO2/5)

Comment: This is zend routing specific question. I think zend interprets url `segments` individually as defined in the `route` `contraints`